# How do I test if a text node is empty?

Tags: xpath

I've got an XML file with this structure:

```
<entry id="1">
    <para>first paragraph</para>
    <para>second paragraph</para>
</entry>
<entry id="2">
    <para></para>
</entry>
```

My XSL needs to do something if it finds an entry has a first  element whose text node is empty (entry id="2" in the example). I've tried this:

```
<xsl:when test="(entry/para[1]/text()='')">
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

A similar code snippet to read an attribute of the  element does work:

```
<xsl:when test="entry[1]/para[@stylename = 'Table Heading']">
```

So I'm doing something wrong with the text()='' selection. A search suggests I should use [not(text())] but I can't figure out how to integrate this in my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`text()=''` requires a text node to be there, but in the case of `<para></para>`, there is no text node to be matched.

So, I'd suggest something like

```
entry/para[1][.='']
```

or

```
entry/para[1][not(text())]
```

Comment: Yes, except that the test has to be true iff "it finds an entry [that] has a **first** element whose text node...". BTW, congrats on having 1000π rep.

Comment: @LarsH Didn't notice the 1000π!  Crazy ;-).  Thanks for the hint, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Quick, someone downvote some of my answers, I exceeded 1000π ;)

Comment: I don't understand why but I try to find images behind text on this page: https://vertigo.com.ua/cannes-guid/ and only `[.='']` from your 2 cases works. Why?

Comment: @Gargo What does your full XPath look like?

Comment: @Gargo What host language is that? I'm afraid I'm the wrong person to ask because I don't know the semantics of the environment/language.